# count number of rows before a value group by another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
id         event_type          datetime
 1         loginScreen     2019-07-14 18:00:40.671529 
 1         loginSuccess    2019-07-14 18:00:50
 1         accountPage     2019-07-14 18:00:51
 1         joinGame        2019-07-14 18:00:53
 1         addCash         2019-07-14 18:00:55
 2         signupScreen    2019-07-14 21:00:00
 2         signupfailed    2019-07-14 21:01:00
 3         signupScreen    2019-07-14 22:00:00
 3         signupSuccess   2019-07-14 22:00:02
 3         joinGame        2019-07-14 22:00:04
```

Output dataframe:

```
 id      number_events_before_join     number_events_after_join
 1              3                           1                                  
 2              0                           0
 3              2                           0
```

I want to count the number of events before joinGame and After joinGame if a user has ever joinGame as a new column added for each user. I tried this, but it is not working correctly:

```
 df['number_events_after_join'] = df.sort_values(by=['id','datetime'],ascending=[False, True]).assign(key=df['event_type'].eq('joinGame').astype(int)).groupby('id')['key'].cumsum()
```

Which I believe returning the number of events after joinGame. How can I modify it to get the number of event before joinGame? or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @WeNYoBen added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little heavy-handed, but it works.

```
groupby = df.groupby('id')
mask = df['event_type'].ne('joinGame')
result = pd.concat([
    groupby.cumcount(ascending=1).rename('number_events_before_join'),
    groupby.cumcount(ascending=0).rename('number_events_after_join')
], axis=1).mask(mask).join(df['id']).groupby('id').first().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
    number_events_before_join  number_events_after_join
id                                                     
1                           3                         1
2                           0                         0
3                           2                         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the after game , we just need get the reversed order to get the before game

```
 df['number_events_before_join'] = df.sort_values(by=['id','datetime'],ascending=[False, True])\
                 .assign(key=df['event_type'].eq('joinGame').astype(int))\
                       .iloc[::-1,:].groupby('id')['key'].cumsum()
```

Update

```
s=df['event_type'].eq('joinGame').astype(int).groupby(df['id']).cumsum().gt(0)
pd.crosstab(df.id[df['event_type'].ne('joinGame')],s)
event_type  False  True 
id                      
1               3      1
2               2      0
3               2      0
```